# apt-get install mysql-server doesn't ask root password and server doesn't start

Tags: apt, mysql, reinstall

I had previously successfully installed `mysql-server` on Ubuntu 16.04 but as I didn't remember root password and had no db created, I tried to reinstall it. I tried many times but it seems that the process does not complete as it does not ask for root password and does not create the mysql directories in `/etc` and `/var/lib`. As a result, the server doesn't start.

This is how I remove mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql* /etc/mysql*
deluser mysql
delgroup mysql
```

Reinstallation log :

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/10.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 207500 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
$
$ ls /etc/my*
ls: cannot access '/etc/my*': No such file or directory
$ ls /var/lib/my*
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/my*': No such file or directory
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
$
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Your inability to access '/var/lib/my*' is not an error. As a regular user, you don't have permission to access the files. You would need to be in superuser mode to see them.

Comment: Even using sudo, /var/lib/my* and /etc/my* are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. I guess this solution might not be suitable in other cases but this is what I did.